# Overlay saying NORMAL

Tags: nvidia, gnome, 17.04

A few minutes after logging in the screen flashes and I am presented with an overlay text saying `NORMAL`, along with it the screens starts to look blurry(like very low resolution). It does not go away and after a few minutes the screen flashes again and I am logged out. Please help me in fixing this

Comment: I don't know what happened but the problem went away after I started the computer today morning. I also switched to unity and then back to gnome. Just listing out whatever I remember doing that might have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by turning off flipping in NVIDIA X Settings, it had something with a feature that is enabled by default and does not work properly in certain systems

Comment: Disabling flipping has not removed this overlay for me. It started after I upgraded to nvidia driver: 440.48.02.